# How to get wireless mobile node's location( x and y coordinates) dynamically using tcl script only?

Tags: mobile, location, tcl, ns2

I am working on a location preserving scheme in VANET. I want to access the current location of mobile node in tcl file in ns2. However, while I have found few solutions, all these solutions are related to C source code; I have not found any solution for use from Tcl code.

The only solution I have found for use from Tcl files is [here](http://www.projectguideline.com/topic/getting-coordinates-of-a-node-in-ns2-using-tcl/)
but it only gives the initial coordinates of a node.
The other solution I know of is [this](https://getch.wordpress.com/tag/node-position/), but that isn't a Tcl solution.

Comment: Can you show exactly what you are doing to get the positions? Reading online resources seems to indicate that `$node set X_` really is how to read the current x-coordinate of a node (and similarly for y and z). You might instead be having problems of _when_ the code is evaluated; that matters a lot.

Comment: For static nodes I am setting initial node position as: 
$node set X_ 
$node set Y_
$node set Z_
then passing these coordinates in proc to access the position at any given time. The problem is that I am unable to get current/updated position of mobile nodes at any given time.